# Mongo projection field that field not same

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

there

My question may be confuse. Let's me explain further more.

I have document for aggregation like this.

```
{
  "metric" : "user_act",
  "stream_id" : "f00001",
  "values" : {
    "likes" : 57,
    "comments" : 0,
    "shares" : 0
  }
}
{
    "metric" : "user_act",
    "stream_id" : "f00002",
    "values" : {
      "likes" : 28,
      "comments" : 0,
      "shares" : 1
    }
}

{
    "metric" : "user_act",
    "stream_id" : "t00001",
    "values" : {
      "favorites" : 5,
      "retweets" : 15
    }
}
```

I would like to calculate engagement by sum likes, comments and shares together. So before calculating, I have to projection data before grouping. I would like to mapping `values.favorites` to `likes`, `values.retweets` to `shares` and `comments` if don't have any data set default to 0.

I try projection like below but does not work because value of second line of `$ifNull` override the first line.

```
{
  $project: {
    "stream_id" : 1, 
    "shares": {
      $ifNull: ["$values.retweets",0],
      $ifNull: ["$values.shares", 0]
    } ,
    "likes": {
      $ifNull: ["$values.favorites",0],
      $ifNull: ["$values.likes", 0]
    } ,
    "comments": {
      $ifNull: ["$values.replys",0],
      $ifNull: ["$values.comments", 0]
    }
  }
}
```

Anyone any idea? Thank you in advanced.

[Update]
I try to projection like this but not work in `case:` how can I check the field exists?

```
{
  $project: {
    "stream_id" : 1,
      "shares": {
        $switch: {
          branches: [
            { case: {$ne: ["$values.retweets", 0]},
              then: {$ifNull: ["$values.retweets", "$values.retweets"]}
            },
            { case: {$ne: ["$values.shares", 0]},
              then: {$ifNull: ["$values.shares", "$values.shares"]}
            }
          ],
          default: 0
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `$cond` projection.

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $project: {
    "stream_id" : 1, 
    "shares": { $cond: [ { $eq:[ { $ifNull: [ "$values.shares", 0 ] }, 0 ] },{ $ifNull: [ "$values.retweets", 0 ] }, "$values.shares" ] },
    "likes": { $cond: [ { $eq:[ { $ifNull: [ "$values.likes", 0 ] }, 0 ] }, { $ifNull: [ "$values.favorites", 0 ] }, "$values.likes" ] },
    "comments": { $cond: [ { $eq:[ { $ifNull: [ "$values.comments", 0] }, 0 ] }, { $ifNull: [ "$values.replys", 0 ] }, "$values.comments" ] }
}})
```

Using `$switch`

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
  $project: {
    "stream_id" : 1,
      "shares": {
        $switch: {
          branches: [
            { case: { $ifNull: [ "$values.shares", false ] },
              then: "$values.shares"
            },
           { case: { $ifNull: [ "$values.retweets", false ] },
              then: "$values.retweets"
            }],
          default: 0
        }
      }
  }
}])
```

Comment: Yeah, It's work for 2 conditions, right? If I have many social like IG or Youtube that name of metrics is not the same. How handle it.

Comment: Precisely. You can nest more conditions but I would recommend fixing it before you inserting  the data into  db  if you have too many of these.

Comment: Sorry, What is your recommend to fixing? I mean, assume I have document like this $values.love in documents. the condition must be many many nested.

Comment: yeah you just have to keep nesting it will become unreadable. Something like `"shares": { $cond: [ { $eq:[ { $ifNull: [ "$values.shares", 0 ] }, 0 ] },{ $cond: [ { $eq:[ { $ifNull: [ "$values.retweets", 0 ] }, 0 ] },{ $ifNull: [ "$values.love", 0 ] }  "$values.retweets" ] }, "$values.shares" ] }`. You can use $switch for better readability.